# huge cached memory, mostly freez system :(

Tags: ram, swap, cache

I have a problem with system memory cache, i think it is bigger than normals. after 5-10 minute of usage, system become unusable and i must restart my "Asus X451-CA" laptop.
this command ran upon user logged in, firefox runed:

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1821       1552        269        377         34        856
-/+ buffers/cache:        661       1159
Swap:         1932          0       1932
```

and after a while system will freeze:

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1821       1649        172        581          0        632
-/+ buffers/cache:       1015        805
Swap:         1932         31       1901
```

more info:

```
matrix@matrix-X451CA:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness 
vm.swappiness = 60
matrix@matrix-X451CA:~$ sysctl vm.min_free_kbytes 
vm.min_free_kbytes = 65536
```

i want more swap space being used and reduce cached memory.
i tried:

```
# sysctl -w vm.swappiness=30
# sysctl -w vm.swappiness=90
# sysctl -w vm.min_free_kbytes=65536
# sysctl -w vm.min_free_kbytes=131072
```

no changes at all.

---

edit:
while system freezes "kswapd0" have most CPU use.
I use Ubuntu 14.04 with 3.13.0-32 kernel.

Comment: requested info already in are main post...

Comment: Ok . Which Ubuntu and which kernel?

Comment: Do you use preload or swapd?

Comment: main post edited.

Comment: Your system only has 2GB of memory, perhaps consider a version of Ubuntu with lower hardware requirements? Also you hit: _"Setting min_free_kbytes too low prevents the system from reclaiming memory. This can result in system hangs and OOM-killing multiple processes. However, setting this parameter to a value that is too high (**5-10% of total system memory**) **will cause your system to become out-of-memory immediately**. Linux is designed to use all available RAM to cache file system data. Setting a high min_free_kbytes value results in the system spending too much time reclaiming memory."_

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do I do when extensive SWAP access makes system dead](http://askubuntu.com/questions/417462/what-do-i-do-when-extensive-swap-access-makes-system-dead)

Comment: I tried to run 14.04 32 bit on 2 GHz pentium dual and 2 gb ram 4 gb swap.It works without any problem with preload.

Comment: I think main issue is "cache become full without swaping". Ubuntu do not utilize swap normally. I had ArchLinux before this and there was no errors. also i had Ubuntu 14.04 before ArchLinux and there was no errors too. Ubuntu must use more swap but does not. I tried higher "vm.swappiness" values but did not helped... :( What to do now?!
I have a fast SSD and i have no problems with high swap usage...