# How to make Ubuntu kill the problematic process when it goes out of RAM?

Tags: ram, swap

So, like most other people, I used to have swap enabled. I'll first describe what was happening when I did.

I'm developing an app that sometimes eats all my RAM. Then what happens is that the system freezes almost completely, which I attribute to heavy swapping. I'm pretty much unable to get out the situation unless I cold-reboot the system.

I tried `swapoff -a` but now, for some reason, the system freezes when I get to 2GB used out of 3.

**I'd just like Ubuntu to kill the problematic process right before the system freezes, so it doesn't get to freezing.**

How it could determine which is the problematic process, is a bit hard to say, but I think simply "kill the process with the highest ram usage, excluding system processes" would be good behavior for my case.

**Any way to get Ubuntu to do what I want?**

**Note:** [This comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417462/what-do-i-do-when-extensive-swap-access-makes-system-dead#comment540171_417478) says that what I want is the default behavior when swap is off, but that's not what I am observing.

Comment: Please rephrase your question to mean "what can I do after the system has frozen".

Comment: @Jos: That's not what I'm after, though. I want Ubuntu to *automatically* avoid the freeze by killing a process, even when I as a human have no idea that a freeze is imminent. Your (deleted) answer did not help, because it required me to know in advance when the system is about to freeze.

Comment: If you've got only 3G RAM with no swap, it's no wonder you're freezing. Why not either add more RAM, or add a swapfile/swap partition?

Comment: @heynnema: About "adding a swap partition", that's what I used to have. Please re-read my first 2 paragraphs. About "adding more RAM": it wouldn't be worth it, considering I have an alternative: install Ubuntu on my other, newer laptop too, and work there. That's what I'm working on right now. It has 8GB RAM. My question was an attempt to skip the hassle.

Comment: @StefanMonov I saw that you had no swap in your question. That's what prompted my comment. Why don't you have a swapfile or swap partition, or why won't you add one to solve your freezing problem?

Comment: @heynnema: I said that I *used* to have swap, and that when I did, I was getting freezes that I attributed to **heavy swapping**. Only in the second paragraph I get to turning off swap. I edited the question to make that more clear.

Comment: @StefanMonov how big was your swap partition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57060/discussion-between-stefan-monov-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 1):

By default Linux has an "oomkiller" ("Out-of-memory killer") which will try to guess which process makes most sense to kill and if neccessary kills it. Unfortunately as you already stated it is rather difficult to make the right guess, so result can be somewhat random, including freezing up your system.

The oomkiller ca be influenced by several means. Check [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html) for some more details on how it works and how to influence it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd appreciate instructions how to do exactly what I want, rather than a broad link.

Comment: @StefanMonov did you read this article in its entirety? It really does address your question, esp if you insist on not having a swapfile or swap partition.

Comment: @heynnema: Sorry but I didn't, I think asking me to read an entire article when I need only a minuscule part of it is asking too much of me ;)

Comment: @StefanMonov you ask a question, you get an answer, and you blow it off without even reviewing what the answer says?!? If you read the article you'd see that it's not as easy as you appear to think. See how many other new answers that you get now.